# Selenium Grid: Unable to start selenium grid hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

after downloading selenium-server-4.0.0.jar from here

```
https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/
```

I put this jar file in the c folder and after that
using cmd I tried launching selenium grid hub using this command

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0.jar hub
```

I'm unable to run the selenium grid hub it shows the following

```
C:\>java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0.jar hub
12:29:21.621 INFO [LogManager$RootLogger.log] - Using the system default encoding
12:29:21.624 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
12:29:22.034 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442,
advertising as tcp://192.168.100.8:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, 
advertising as tcp://192.168.100.8:4443]
12:29:22.073 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://192.168.100.8:4442 and 
tcp://192.168.100.8:4443
12:29:22.094 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
12:29:23.110 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
12:29:24.443 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium Hub 4.0.0 (revision 3a21814679): 
http://192.168.100.8:4444
```

I tried putting this URL in chrome browser

```
http://192.168.100.8:4444
```

then it shows this

```
Unable to find /index.html
```

Comment: Looks absolutely fine. The url for the grid console is now ```http://192.168.100.8:4444/ui/index.html#/```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. It turns out it was a java problem . I had some old jdk8 version. After switching to jdk11 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the `selenium-server-4.0.0.jar` was corrupted or wasn't downloaded properly.

Delete the current Selenium Server jar and download a fresh copy from the [Downloads](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) page.

Start the HUB as:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\My Own Downloads\SeleniumServer>java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0.jar hub
```

You will see the following log messages:

```
15:07:34.490 INFO [LogManager$RootLogger.log] - Using the system default encoding
15:07:34.490 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
15:07:35.058 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442, advertising as tcp://192.168.225.29:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, advertising as tcp://192.168.225.29:4443]
15:07:35.136 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://192.168.225.29:4442 and tcp://192.168.225.29:4443
15:07:35.168 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
15:07:36.169 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
15:07:37.842 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium Hub 4.0.0 (revision 3a21814679): http://192.168.225.29:4444
```

Now you can access the Selenium Grid console accessing either of the urls:

- *`http://localhost:4444`*
- *`http://192.168.225.29:4444`*

Snapshot of the Console:

[image: SeleniumHub]